# Is to possible to send clicks to all windows setup.exe installers (windows programs)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-installer

What I am attempting to achieve at surface level seems relatively simple: hack a windows installer to run without any user input.

Unfortunately, I don't have an msi and running the installer with the silent install tag yields no result. I've also looked into wrapping the .exe into a .msi, but lead to a dead end.

Then, I figured that since an installer, after all is a windows program, maybe I can send mouse clicks and keyboard strokes to it.

However, I could not. The short test program ran with no errors, but the checkbox still wasn't checked.

[image: screenshot]

I tested this method with other programs and it works. My guess is that for SendMessage() to work, the application has to be built to listen for and respond the messages?

Next, I figured that I could forcibly send a mouse click using the SendInput() function

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND handle = (HWND)0x008105CC;

    GetWindowRect(handle, &rec);

    double x = rec.left;
    double y = (rec.top + rec.bottom) / 2;

    LPARAM lparam = MAKELPARAM(x, y);

    SetCursorPos(x, y);

    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dx = 0;
    input.mi.dy = 0;
    input.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP);
    input.mi.mouseData = 0;
    input.mi.dwExtraInfo = NULL;
    input.mi.time = 0;

    SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

    return 0;
}
```

However, that also failed! Once again, I tested checking another checkbox in another application, and it worked. So, I'm very confused as to why sending clicks, which I expected would be independent of a specific program process, doesn't work in all programs???

Comment: In an ideal world you'd work out what the installer did, and repackage it

Comment: In reality when testing your correctly determining the HWND dynamically?

Comment: Did you check with the software provider and see if they have any command line parameters for silent or automated installs?

Comment: The other problem would be if the installer runs elevated, then you need to run your program elevated (otherwise it won't be able to interact).

Comment: If the installer is running elevated, [UIPI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vishalsi/archive/2006/11/30/what-is-user-interface-privilege-isolation-uipi-on-vista.aspx) will block the message, unless the installer explicitly allows the message to pass through (which it is likely not doing): "*A lower privilege process cannot: ... **- SendMessage or PostMessage to higher privilege application windows**. These application programming interfaces (APIs) return success but silently drop the window message.*" See [Windows Integrity Mechanism Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx)

Comment: That being said, `SendInput()` should work since it [injects directly into the same input queue that the mouse driver posts to](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773), so the installer window (and UIPI) should not know the difference between simulated input and real input. However, the code shown is sending the simulated clicks to screen coordinates 0x0, not to the checkbox coordinates. If you use `SetCursorPos()` to position the mouse beforehand, **don't** use the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag, as you want the clicks to be relative to the cursor's *current* position.

Comment: That being said, you might consider using **UI Automation** instead. Since you already have the `HWND`, use [`AccessibleObjectFromWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978.aspx) to retrieve the checkbox's [`IAccessible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466.aspx) interface and then call its [`accDoDefaultAction()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318470.aspx) method. The "default action" of a checkbox is to toggle the state of its checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) for things like that:

> AutoIt v3 is a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting. It uses a combination of simulated keystrokes, mouse movement and window/control manipulation in order to automate tasks in a way not possible or reliable with other languages (e.g. VBScript and SendKeys). AutoIt is also very small, self-contained and will run on all versions of Windows out-of-the-box with no annoying “runtimes” required!
>   AutoIt was initially designed for PC “roll out” situations to reliably automate and configure thousands of PCs. Over time it has become a powerful language that supports complex expressions, user functions, loops and everything else that veteran scripters would expect.